# Что возвращает метод GetAssetPath, если объект пустой? Как проверить пустая строка пришла или нет ?(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, строки

Как проверить пришло пустое значение или нет ? Что возвращает GetAssetPath, если префаб null?

```
string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(tempPrefab);
if(path == ... ) {}
```

Comment: File.Exists(Path) ? Application.dataPath (папка Assets)

Comment: @Yaroslav Проверю позже . Спасибо

Comment: .prefub не забудь.